# If it isn't Base64, what might it be?

Tags: vb.net, base64, decoding

**Original Question**

> I'm using an API to get a thumbnail image that I uploaded.  Instead of providing me with a url to the image, the service returns me a garbles text string that I thought was Base64.  However, all of my attempts to decode this string have failed. Does anyone have any ideas of what object types the service might be returning me?  If it's not base64, what would it be?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt8zc.png) on imgur of the API response

**Answer to Original Question**

> @Andrew Tran: pointed out that the response I was getting looked like it was the raw binary data for the png file.  This helped correct my lack of experience with Base64 and led me to some further research.

**First Attempt at downloading the file**

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\username\lpImages\img1.png"
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(thumbnail)
fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
fs.Close()
```

**This never worked... so I talked with a coworker and finally realized my mistake**

I had been using an abstracted class to call the API and had glazed over the fact that under the hood the "request" method was actually reading the return stream into a string.  The service returned the image png file as a stream, but the request method was converting this raw stream.  Once I created a different request method I was able to get the png as a stream.  From there it was relatively easy to use it as I intended: attaching the images as LinkedResources to an email that I then send out.

Original request method code

```
response = theRequest.GetResponse
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
lp_response.response = reader.ReadToEnd
```

New request code I wrote instead

```
lp_response.response = theRequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
```

VB.Net code to handle the stream (this is just a snippet where I'm building a List of LinkedResources to pass to my email function; just to give an idea of how I'm using it)

```
Dim document As Stream = LPApi.GetDocumentThumbnail(d("id").ToString)
Dim mediaType As String = Utils.GetContentType(Path.GetExtension(d("file_name")))
Dim lrDocument As New LinkedResource(document, mediaType)
lrDocument.ContentId = d("id").ToString
```

Thanks to everyone who commented.  I'm pretty inexperienced when it comes to the deeper architecture of web requests/responses and data serialization.  Any good learning resources would be helpful; otherwise I'll just keep Googling :)

Comment: doesnt "the service" provide some documentation for their API?

Comment: Can you upload the image to an image hosting service and link it?  like imgur or something?

Comment: if it looks like numbers and single case letters it could be base 36: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36, this is used for financial codes such as Cusips.

Comment: I've edited my initial question to include a link to a screenshot of what the service returns.

Comment: it looks like the binary image itself as a PNG - certainly not "text"

Comment: @Plutonix, this is what is returned to me from the service.  Do you know if there still a way to decode it to save to a local file system?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on HOW was it returned to you? what is the function you used to get it? how is it declared or defined? is this a desktop app or ASP or what? **what does the API documentation say it returns?**

Comment: @Plutonix, I'm sorry, I'm still learning how to ask these types of questions.  My code is VB.Net running as part of a WCF service.  This service listens to be notified from a Project-Management (in our case LiquidPlanner) system of a task update and then makes GET HttpWebRequests to LiquidPlanner's API for various information.  I then use that info to compose html emails and send them to the people involved with the task.

Comment: @OregonAppDev  As you do additional research and refine your question based on others' suggestions, consider editing your question to include these details for future users who may not read / do not want to read the entire comment thread.  You may also want to consider putting some of the code you are using to write the file to the file system in your question.  Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks @xDaevax, will do!  I'll try to make sure the question gives a brief summary of the comments, what I tried, and the solution that was reached.  Quick question - is it normal practice to update the Question title to better reflect the solution, or is the original question title generally preserved?

Comment: @OregonAppDev  I would say to make any edits necessary to the question to improve the clarity and relevance as long as the question is the same question.  See here for further discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts

Comment: @xDaevax, thanks for the meta link.  I've just now made an edit to summarize the SO question thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's being encoded at all.

The IHDR chunk start is clearly visible and in plaintext at the start of the file.

Comment: Ok, so this is just a raw stream of the PNG?  Could I then save this directly to my file system if need be?  Ultimately I need to save it so I can then attach it to an email and reference it in the inline email body.

Comment: Yes, it appears that you're getting the binary data. Save it to your file system with a PNG extension and it should fire right up.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I think you're right, so maybe it's just an issue now of me figuring out how to correctly write it to my filesystem.  I was able to create a png with this code but when trying to open it I get the message that "the file appears to be damages, corrupted, or is too large."

I'll add the file save code to my original question.

Comment: I accepted your answer as you answered the original question I posted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to use `HttpWebRequest` to download binary data, then convert the response to a string, just to try to convert that string back into binary data to save it to a file.

If you're getting an `HttpWebResponse` object, you should be able to use [HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) to get a stream for the image data. Then you should be able to copy the image data straight into your filestream using [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx).

Comment: This is good info - it's exactly what my coworker recommended when I was discussing it with him.  I'd upvote your answer if I had enough SO reputation.  This is my first question... but hopefully this will help someone else someday.